# Xamarin.Forms - Webview (with local files) not working on Windows Phone 8.1 & 10

Tags: c#, webview, xamarin.forms

I want to use WebView to access local HTML files (in Xamarin.forms) on windows phone 8.1/10. I have it successfully working on Android however on windows phone, I get an error that says "Action was Cancelled" (Testing on Lumia 950).

I am new to Xamarin and went through the documentation on their website, the sample they have provided works with windows phone 8.0 and seems outdated as I was unable to deploy that (sample project) on to my Lumia 950.

Please help out on how to approach this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Please check your HTML, something is wrong. Try to display something like

```html
<h1>Hello</h1>
```

It should be fine